# Bamboo + iOS - Disable Code Signing

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, bamboo

I'd like to use Bamboo to do continuous builds for an iOS project. The project is setup for code signing, but I don't want to install the certificates on the build machine. As a result, I need to disable code signing at build time. From the command line, I can get this to work using a command along the following lines:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos6.0 -project MyProject.xcodeproj \
  -alltargets -configuration Debug \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

The last two items are the key. Unfortunately, I don't know where to put them in the Bamboo Task configuration such that they're actually passed to the `xcodebuild` command.

Anyone know how to accomplish this *without* disabling code signing in the project file itself?

Comment: I too would like to do this, how did you get on?

Comment: I still haven't gotten it working. I gave up and just started code signing.

Answer (score 0):

Each bamboo plan has Plan variables you can set. On the Plan Configuration page there is a tab `Variables`. Any Variables set there will be passed to the Bamboo script
eg you can set a variable for `codeSignId` in the Plan variable page and access it in the build script like this

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos6.0 -project MyProject.xcodeproj \
  -alltargets -configuration Debug \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=${bamboo.CodeSignID} CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```